# Vauxhall/Opel Astra H How to remove front door electrical connector

Tags: electrical, vauxhall, opel, astra, connector

The front door electrical connector on the Astra Mk5 H,  is a rectangular multiplug. Is there a special technique for pulling it off. Are there clips which must be released first?

Any tips appreciated.

(I haven't uploaded a picture as I'd like a reply from someone who has experience of this connector, rather than people just guessing)

Edit... picture added. I figured it out, though guesses are welcome!

[image: Astra H Door Multiplug]

Comment: If I had the pic, I wouldn't need to guess.

Comment: Generally manufacturers don't like to put the door electrical connect in a wet zone. What I've seen is wiring harnesses with rubber / plastic overmold seals, with the hardshell plastic electrical connectors far removed from the door hinge area.  Are you looking at a protective overmold seal?  Another recommendation: purchase the service manual!  They will have photos that apply to your vehicle.

Comment: Maybe it's like what they do on Chrysler's now and there are actually multiple plugs with a rubber boot over the harness. The plugs are just held in place by a plastic carrier.

Comment: @Paulster2 Ok, so not posting the pic was laziness on my part, i admit it! But my point stands... if you see a pic and you've never got your hands on one of these connectors personally, then you're just guessing... which is exactly what I'll be doing later today with a variety of prying tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pry up on top the center portion of the plug with a small screw driver and it will slide up and release the latch on the connector. Then the plug slides off.

Answer (score 0):

Ben is correct, although I'd already figured it out by this point.
This connector contains a weatherproof seal, which combined with the 34 pins would make it difficult to remove. So this plug cleverly has a clip whose main purpose is to evenly prise the plug out of it's socket as you slide it upwards. A very clever design.

Here it is released
[image: Astra H Door connector (released)]

And the red-herring is the clip which keeps the rubber boot in place. Shown here unclipped
[image]

Finally, I doubt there is anyone quite as stupid as me... but when you have to leave the car to go  and get your multimeter - don't slam the door shut with the connector dangling loose. It won't end well!